# Unity3D-C# array initialization and population: Null Reference - Object reference not set

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to save my game data. At the point of 'copy game data into serializable class objects' I'm having an issue. Here is my code:

```
public static void Save()
{
    // set save file
    .
    .

    // import game data to serializable class
    PlayerData data = new PlayerData();

    GameObject[] tiles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tile");
    int i = 0;
    print (data.tiles.Length);  // prints as expected (initialization in constructor)
    foreach(GameObject tile in tiles)
    {
        data.tiles[i].X = tile.GetComponent<TileScript>().X;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        //null reference: object reference not set to an instance of object

        i++;
    }
    .
    .
    .
    print ("Game Saved!");
}
```

And here is the class I'm trying to save my game data into:

```
[Serializable]
class PlayerData
{
    public class Building
    {
        public int index;
    }
    public class Tile
    {
        public int X,Y;
        .
        .
    }

    public Tile[] tiles;

    public PlayerData()
    {
        tiles = new Tile[40];

    }
}
```

I cannot locate the mistake I make. Is there a special case with the `[Serializable]` class member initialization? Where do I make the mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You don't add anything to the tiles array, therefore data.tiles[i] returns null and thus fails to access the X member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of `tiles` is initialized to the default value of `Tile`. If `Tile` is a reference-type (i.e., a `class` rather than a `struct`), then it will be `null`. In addition to creating the array, you need to initialize each element to a new `Tile` object:

```
public Tile[] tiles;

public PlayerData()
{
    tiles = new Tile[40];
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; i++)
        tiles[i] = new Tile();
}
```

When you don't do this and you try to access the data at:

```
data.tiles[i].X
```

`data.tiles[i]` will return `null`. Attempting to access the `X` member on the `null` reference naturally throws your `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Rookie mistake. I think I need to refresh my C# reading. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: so what tiles = new Tile[40]; does

Comment: @user2320445: It creates a `Tile[]` array with 40 `null` entries. That is: `tiles[0]` is `null`, `tiles[1]` is `null`, `tiles[39]` is `null`. Imagine if `Tile` didn't have a public parameterless constructor, or had several constructor overloads, what should `tiles = new Tile[40]` do to fill the elements? What if you didn't want to create _new_ `Tile` objects, but instead wanted to fill the array with _existing_ `Tile` objects you already had; does it make sense to do the work instantiating a bunch of `Tile` objects to fill the array just to throw them away?